# How does Flash Translation Layer store mapping data, unusable block and super block?

Tags: filesystems, flash-memory, zfs, solid-state-drive, jffs2

Does `ftl` have private storage space that is not flash？

If not, how does `ftl` store those meta data while avoiding `wear leveling`.

Actually I don’t know if there is a super block in `ftl`, but if you want to locate the mapping data and unusable block whose physical address changes frequently, a certain physical address may be needed. The content on this physical address must change frequently, how To avoid wear leveling of this physical address?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions to this problem and it's very intertwined with the data representation that the drive uses to store its data, so I'm sure it differs a lot based on the drive / manufacturer. I'll just outline a general approach that could work.

Let's say you design an FTL that maintains several fixed-size, append-only "logs", and for simplicity we always have one "active" log that all writes are appended to. If the user is issuing random writes, the order of LBAs in the active log will be random too. When the active log fills all the space allocated to it, it gets "frozen" and we switch the active log to some empty log elsewhere in the flash. As the data in the frozen log becomes stale, we will eventually need to garbage collect it by copying any still-referenced blocks to a different log before erasing the original so that it can be reused for new writes.

Now, for each write to a log, nothing in our interface so far requires that the blocks be exactly 4KiB (or whatever), so you could append a small header to the data that tells you what its LBA is, and perhaps some other metadata -- write sequence number so you can tell if it's the most recent copy of a block, and maybe a checksum for read integrity checking. When a write finishes, you update an in-RAM copy of the map with the new location for the LBAs that were updated (RAM inside the SSD, not RAM for the main CPU of the computer obviously).

If the FTL crashes or loses power, you can reconstruct the map by reading all headers from all the logs. The downside is that scanning the logs will scale `O(number of logs * number of blocks per log)`, so you optimize that somehow:

- you could write the headers to a separate part of the disk by themselves so that you can scan them without also reading the user data (same big-O runtime but a lot faster in practice)
- you could periodically flush the in-RAM copy of the map to flash somewhere, along with the latest IO sequence number, so that you only have to read the parts of the logs that were written since the latest map flush

  - How do you find the portion of the log to start scanning from? do a binary search on the IO sequence numbers in the log headers. So the boot runtime is now `O(number of logs * (log_2(number of blocks per log) + number of blocks that need to be scanned))`
  - How do you know when to stop scanning? either you recognize that all data in the block you read is 1's because that part of the log hasn't been written to yet, or you recognize that the checksum and data don't match.
  - Minor optimization: during a clean shutdown, always write the map to flash, so that this binary search + scanning only needs to happen if there's a crash or unclean shutdown.

So far, this lowers how often you need to write the map by a lot, but it's still probably too often to overwrite it to a fixed location for a drive with a very long lifetime. To resolve that, we have to cycle where we write the map:

- The simplest solution would be to designate a small set of X special logs to store all map data and write to them like a circular buffer, where X is chosen to make the map updates last the expected lifetime of the device. To find the most recent map in the log on boot, you'd do binary search within those logs to find the last one that was written. So boot = `O(X * log_2(number of maps per log) + runtime to scan the other logs if unclean shutdown)`.
- Probably a more optimal solution (but one that might be more complicated), would include the map writes directly into the logs where the updates are happening. Then you need some way to find where the maps are at boot time -- the most obvious way to do that would be to write the map into the beginning of each active log, or you could allow arbitrary map writes by adding backpointers into the block headers that point back to the latest map in their log.

Another aspect of this is that full map flushes could be expensive, which would add tail latency if it ever interferes with the performance of user IOs -- would it be better to allow incremental updates? That's when you start looking at using something like a log-structured merge (LSM) tree to store your map, so that each incremental write is pretty small and you can amortize the full map write cost.

Obviously there are a bunch of tiny details that this explanation leaves out, but hopefully that's enough to get you started. :-)